# extjs Tree View - referring to Nodes programmatically

Tags: extjs

I have defined a TreeView, and when it gets rendered to the HTML page, the first element is a DIV with the id of my TreeView:

```
<div id="levelTreePanel" class="x-panel x-tree-panel x-tree-lines x-grid 
x-grid-header-hidden x-panel-default" style="height: 120px; width: 320px; " 
role="presentation">
...
</div>
```

There are some nested DIVs under that, with Id's like 'treeview-xxxx' and 'ext-genxxxx'
Then there's a TABLE
In cells of the table are Divs that render each of the Nodes in my Tree data.
I would like to be able to reference these Divs that represent my Nodes from Javascript, but the generated Node-Divs don't have Ids at all. I've tried assigning 'id' attributes to the nodes of the Tree data, but these don't get rendered anywhere on the resulting HTML.

Is there a way to get the framework to assign Id values to the Nodes of the tree?
Is this what the 'childEls' or 'tpl' properties are for?

Comment: When in Rome do like Romans do.  My suggestion is to read the guides a bit about components and how to work with them. You don't want to use a framework like ExtJS and go around it fighting it every turn to get what you need. Instead embrace it, learn it and go with the flow.

Comment: @DmitryB: It's not fighting against ExtJS - it's simply looking for a way how to get the corresponding view element for the data node of a tree. Sadly, there I haven't found such the way neither and it seems the it none. Have you learned it (read the guides to help)?
To be specific: how do you colorize (style) some item of the tree panel?

Comment: @DmitryB: I have read the documentation, and it is deficient in this very specific and unusual requirement - no surprise there.

Comment: @PeterIvan: styling an item is easy, you can use the iconCls attribute to assign a CSS class to it.

Comment: @George Seems you found the right documentation to help Peter :) . Please do tell us what it is you are trying to do so that perhaps we can find a good recommendation.

Comment: @George: Now we found 2 solutions together: 1. I have to assign a css config option to colorify the node. 2. If you can assign unique css to the item, then you can find the corresponding node via Ext.dom.Query.select("TD[className~=uniqueCss]", treeViewDiv).